# Excel Page size changing between screen sizes

Tags: excel, scale, dashboard, screen-size

I have created an interactive dashboard for a client. They have raised a minor issue that sees some people using a laptop screen and others using another (typically larger) monitor. Is there a way to automatically scale the size accordingly so that the user can see the whole dashboard regardless of terminal without scrolling etc.

I don't even know where to start other than looking through standard excel functionality

TIA

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.